# Why is accuracy very low and losses high and fluctuating for cnn-lstm

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras

Below given is my cnn-lstm architecture.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same'), 
                          input_shape=(10,128, 128 ,1))) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='same')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding='same')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))


model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((8, 8, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding='same')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='same')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (2, 2), padding='same')))

model.compile(optimizer='RMSProp', loss='mse', metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error','mean_squared_error','accuracy'])

data = np.load(r"/content/boxing_d1.npy")
print (data.shape)
(x_train,x_test) = train_test_split(data)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

print (x_train.shape)
print (x_test.shape)
history = model.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=1,
                shuffle=False,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

encoded_imgs = model.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = model.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

I am trying to extract the compressed representation of videos using cnn-lstm inorder to use it for classification purposes using kmeans. Here is the output after a single set of training. Why are the metrics fluctuating as shown in the output. Also i trained a similar model but further training increases the validation and training loss. Ill post a link if someone would like to take a look at it.

[image: model accuracy after first set]

[image: model loss after first set]

[image: model accuracy after second set]

[image: model loss after second set]

What is actually wrong here? is it the number of neurons or hidden layers or has it got something to do with the data im feeding?